# Updating two entries from two separate SQL tables

Tags: sql, join

I am trying to update the title of a publication and the year of the journal (corresponding to it). Do I need to do two separate queries? Or can I do this in one query?

```
%%sql
    /* Change the title of an article and its publication year. */
    UPDATE publication
    SET title = "Sleepy", year = 2017
    JOIN journal
        ON publication.ID = journal.ID
    WHERE title = "test title";
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you even from clause brah?

Comment: @WEI_DBA sqlite with Jupyter notebook I believe

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax to update multiple tables:

UPDATE table1, table2, ...
SET column1 = expression1,
    column2 = expression2,
    ...
WHERE table1.column = table2.column
[AND conditions];

Comment: `UPDATE publication, journal
SET title = "Sleepy", year = 2017
WHERE  publication.ID = journal.ID [AND title = "test title"];`
Error: `near ",": syntax error`

Comment: Remove from the query "[" `s.

Comment: UPDATE publication, journal SET title = "Sleepy", year = 2017 WHERE publication.ID = journal.ID AND title = "test title";

Comment: Same error, it is getting tripped up on one of the commas

Comment: Try to replace " with `

Answer (score 0):

See if this works. It's confusing what columns belong to which table without a schema.

```
UPDATE publication
    SET title = "Sleepy", year = 2017    
    WHERE title = "test title" and ID in (Select ID From journal);
```